# FastAPI Uvicorn run without console

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

My Question is, is it possible to run uvicorn (fastapi) without a console?
I use it, like in the tutorial, but people which use also my server close the console. How can i let it work in the background?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
uvicorn.run("main:app", host="192.168.209.126", port=8080)
```

I tried to change my filename to main.pyw, but that didnt help

Comment: we use this https://nssm.cc/ to run uvicorn as a service in the background in Windows

Answer (score 3):

In Linux, you can use **screen/tmux** for running a task in background.

For example, with **screen**, you first open a new terminal by

```
screen -S new_screen
```

It brings you a terminal, run your code here.

```
python app.py
```

Then you press **Ctrl + A + D** for detaching, leave it run in background.

For more, see **man** page.

Comment: Thx for your comment, maybe that will help someone else, but I have Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [**`-D`** -- (daemon mode)](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#daemon) flag of gunicorn as,

```
gunicorn main:app -D
                  ^^^
```

Comment: Thx, I gonna try that! What is the difference between uvicorn and gunicorn?

Comment: to use with FastAPI, you might need the following : 
gunicorn --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --bind '127.0.0.1:8000' --daemon main:app

Answer (score 0):

You may try pm2(a nodejs tool):

```bash
# install pm2 first
# npm install -g pm2
pm2 start main.py --name my_app --interpreter python3
```

In main.py:

```py
import uvicorn
# ...
uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Then you can manage "my_app" easily:

```bash
pm2 status # view pm2 programs
pm2 restart my_app
```